# Chat indicates that I don't have enough reputation to participate, even though I clearly do

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, chat

I was about to chat but the chat system told me I needed at least 20 reps to do so. [My account](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/6040/matt-) seems to have been zeroed

I have over 2000 [at programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/1069/matt-ellen) and over 5000 at [EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/3559/matt), so I should be able to chat.

Apparently I'm not the only user affected, as the picture below should show, although I can't tell if they're having problems because I can't chat with them.

[image: high lighted users with 0 rep that should have more]

The image high lights [Cerberus](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3420/cerberus), [Grace Note](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/757/grace-note), [Stefano Palazzo](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2042/stefano-palazzo) and [Vitaly](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2841/vitaly). All these users have more than 20 reps, but the system seems to be ignoring that.

Comment: Noticed; working on it.

Comment: It's spelled "Eeeek!" :)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: No, it's not. An Eeeek! post is something different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some sort of fail (still investigating that) in chat's API handling caused chat to not know about any Stack Exchange sites – and thus users whose chat rep was updated during this fail time ended up with a reputation of 0. This should be fixed for everyone (at least after hitting F5); if this is not the case for someone, I'm hanging out in [the Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), so let me know there.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have 26 rep and am getting a notification that I must have 20 rep to chat.

Comment: This problem seems to have reappeared. I have 52k in TeX.se and 0 on the global site.  Logging in and out and closing the browser hasn't helped.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yeah, same issue. Very weird. Fixed now, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be several people who have been locked out of the chat, and meeting other barriers that would indicate that their rep is 0.

I believe (and hope) this is just a minor glitch following a number of Rep-related problems today. The tech guys in charge are aware of this, and they are on the case.